# How do I avoid download images on all docker hosts which are part of my swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a swarm setup which has around 6 nodes. Whenever I execute a docker run or docker pull command from the swarm manager it downloads the new image on all the swarm nodes.

This is creating data redundancy and choking my network.
Is there any way I can avoid this ?

Comment: Try using this https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-your-own-registry-2/

Answer (score 1):

Swarm Nodes need Images available to them by design. That will help swarm to start the container on an available node **immediately** when current node hosting the container crashes or current hosting node goes into maintenance (Drain Mode).

On the other hand docker Images will be pulled one time only, and you can use them until you upgrade your service.

Another one, Docker is designed for microservices, If you Image getting too large, Maybe you should try to cut it down to multiple containers.

Comment: That's correct. Each node needs a copy of the Images in its own cache.